# Why arrow class member functions within Typescript classes don't recognize default values for parameter properties?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use feature called [constructor parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) within an example class

```
class Human {
  constructor(public gender: string = "male") {}

  printGenderFunction(): void {
    console.log("printGenderFunction", this.gender);
  }

  printGenderArrow = () => console.log(this.gender); // TS compiler error: Property 'gender' is used before its initialization.
}
let human = new Human("female");
console.log(human.gender);
human.printGenderFunction();
```

same code but without the use of the constructor parameter properties works

```
class NewHuman {
  public gender: string;
  constructor(gender: string = "male") {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  printGenderFunction(): void {
    console.log("printGenderFunction", this.gender);
  }

  printGenderArrow = () => console.log("printGenderArrow", this.gender); // No errors here
}

let newHuman = new NewHuman("female");
console.log(human.gender);
newHuman.printGenderFunction();
newHuman.printGenderArrow();
```

Why this happens? I thought that constructor parameter properties are meant to be a replacement for the `gender` property initializations like in the class `NewHuman`

Comment: [I'm not able to reproduce the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASCuBbMA7aBvAUNawD2KEALgE7zBF4kAUADvAEYgCWw0A5gKYoAmnJALmjESzFO2gBeaACJkITjICUGAL6Zs0WqJREA4tz4kAYvBQVmBakqEA3PMx4ZNOfITwKAdCDztqM7TF9Q35TcyJLFBkAGmgiAAtmCE8uXn4lAG5NdU1A3QM0kgBBEhI8AHcpaGspAD5cAggPTm9fagSklJCSTMx1BSJoeKRUKpROSoRkFH8AM055RV63Jq8fP2HprsLezdRPPODCsIsrTKA)

Comment: Turns out the issue is with a specific tsconfig.json configuration. For the TS version 4.3.5, the following combination of target, module, lib revealed the issue:
"target": "ESNEXT",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["ES2020","DOM"].

Comment: also works with "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM"
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as comments said you,

> Turns out the issue is with a specific tsconfig.json configuration. For the TS version 4.3.5, the following combination of target, module, lib revealed the issue: "target": "ESNEXT", "module": "commonjs", "lib": ["ES2020","DOM"]. – `Evgeny Vinnik`

it depends on version of ECMAScript target. Why? For older versions, properties are pushed to the constructor. Like this:

```js
class NewHuman {
  constructor(gender = "male") {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.printGenderArrow = () => console.log("printGenderArrow", this.gender); // It's simply error
  }

  printGenderFunction() {
    console.log("printGenderFunction", this.gender);
  }
}
```

Or this

```js
function NewHuman(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.printGenderArrow = function () {console.log("printGenderArrow", this.gender);}
}

NewHuman.prototype.printGenderFunction = function () {
    console.log("printGenderFunction", this.gender);
  }
```

If you have ES2020+, native properties are used, so there's no problem! Of course, this error is Microsoft's mistake because it makes sense that the constructor parameter properties are pushed before the normal ones. You can [post an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new/choose).